# PowerShell executing exe with arguments

Tags: powershell, spaces

I wrote a PowerShell script to execute exe with arguments which has spaces but it keeps failing, not reading the full path.

```cs
$now     = Get-Date -format "MM_dd_yyyy"
$onepath ="C:\Program Files (x86)\GoFileRoom\IWMUploadDocuments\logs\"
$scpath  = "F:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\"
$onefile = "IWMUploadDocumentsLog$now.txt"
$script  = "check_log3.exe"

& "$scpath$script" -p "Error Logging into GFR" -l "$onepath$onefile" -c 1 
Write-Output "$onepath$onefile"
```

Here is the output:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> F:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\onesource.ps1
    Cannot read 'C:\Program'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\GoFileRoom\IWMUploadDocuments\logs\IWMUploadDocumentsLog10_22_2018.txt
```

Comment: Try inner apostrophes ˙"'$onepath$onefile'"˙ or double quotes as `"""""$onepath$onefile"""""`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need an additional set of quotes around the argument for the parameter `-l`:

```
& "$scpath$script" -p "Error Logging into GFR" -l "`"$onepath$onefile`"" -c 1
```

Or try [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) the arguments:

```
$params = '-p', 'Error Logging into GFR',
          '-l', "$onepath$onefile",
          '-c', 1

& "$scpath$script" @params
```

Comment: Does it work if you manually invoke the expanded command (without using variables) in a PowerShell console? Does it work if you do the same in a CMD window?

Comment: PS F:\Program Files\NSClient++> .\scripts\check_log3.exe -p "Error Logging into GFR" -l "C:\Program Files (x86)\GoFileRo
om\IWMUploadDocuments\logs\IWMUploadDocumentsLog06_22_2018.txt"
Cannot read 'C:\Program'

Comment: Then the problem is with the command you're invoking, not with PowerShell. Try using short paths, or put the file in a path that doesn't have spaces in it.

Comment: It works fine when i move the files into a non space folder.